# Bicycle rear wheel cracking sound

Tags: wheels

https://streamable.com/7q86n7

I have a new bike that makes a cracking sound when cycling. We tried people of all sizes and the rear wheel makes this cracking sound.

Anyone has any idea what can be the root cause? Appreciate it. Have managed to take a video of it.

Comment: Does it make the sound when you just rotate the wheel around the axle? Does it make the sound when you backpedal or when you pedal with the wheel raised above the floor? Are you really sure it is the wheel and not the cranks? Does the sound continue when you stop pedalling?

Comment: Anyway, I supoose the bike is covered by the warranty and you can bring it back to the shop.

Comment: Are you talking about the popping sound?  I would suspect that that is due to the spokes rubbing as they break in.